# how can I terminate a android thread running with local method?

Tags: android, multithreading, native

I need terminate my background thread before call app_exit(), but sometimes the thread is still running native method, how can i kill it？ the thread just called one native function, normally it will finish running after the native function return. Is there any way to terminate the thread if the native function didn't return?

```
 testthread = new thread(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
           ret = nativeMethod();
      }
 };

 testthread.start();
```

thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html. check the java docs the methods and their use

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna be a pure java solution. (w/o android APIs)
If you have to wait for the end of the native call, wait for it in the exit function. E.g. with a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) which is the easiest way (`await` in exit and `countDown` in your thread, after the call to the native method), or with wait/notify.

Comment: thanks! running flag or .interrupt() method cannot make it stopped since there is no chance to let the the thread check the flag and native function cannot respond to the interrupt.

Comment: The thread need be terminated before app exit, otherwise there will be duplicated operations when user open the app again.

Comment: Yes noticed it, that the solution is not ok. Then just wait for the finish of the call before completely shutting down. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Is nativeMethod() something you control? If so, there is nothing to stop you from implementing some syncronization between Java and native that said method can check (assuming it's in a loop or such)

Comment: nativeMethod() is supported by xx.so, I cannot control or communicate with this function once it has been executed, i don't know whether there has some method can make this native method stop and then the thread can exit, now i can only do is to wait it's finishing. BTW,the nativeMethod() need parsing some media files and store results to a file, it may need long time to finish it's work if there exist many media files on sd card.

Comment: And what's the problem with waiting for the results? (In the way I proposed or any other way)